# Como verificar se a data dentro do DateTime é inválida?

Tags: php, doctrine-2

Trabalho em uma aplicação com PHP 5.5 + Symfony 2 + Doctrine.

Em uma das tabelas dessa aplicação há um campo `updated_at` que é inicialmente `NULL`. Entretanto, quando dou um `getUpdatedAt()` nessa entidade, me é retornado um objeto do tipo `\DateTime`, e cujo conteúdo é o seguinte:

```
object(DateTime)#1064 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(27) "-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(17) "America/Sao_Paulo"
}
```

Como testar, sem muitas gambiarras, se esse objeto foi gerado a partir de uma data nula?

Comment: O problema é que aí ele já foi criado como data! Se tivesse um `DateTime::createFromFormat` internamente daria para fazer um `$date instanceof DateTime` para verificar!

Comment: Não tem como fazer uma verificação do atributo puro que vem do banco para depois verificar? algo do tipo `if ($data->updated_at !== NULL) { $data->getUpdatedAt() }` ?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters é uma possibilidade, posso tentar verificar dentro da própria entidade. Mas não queria ter que fazer isso com todas as classes que possuem um campo de data que pode ser nulo.

Comment: Faz um [`Trait`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php)! Você está usando o PHP 5.5. Dá pra fazer uma herança horizontal, onde todas as classes que implementar esse `Trait` vai ter esse método com as verificações. Eu já fiz isso no `Laravel`

Comment: isso ajuda?
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504913/verify-valid-date-using-phps-datetime-class[/link]

Comment: Achei um jeito, vejam minha resposta. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o jeito certo.

Se eu tento criar um objeto \DateTime a partir de uma data inválida:

```
$data = new \DateTime('00-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Basta verificar os eventuais erros que o construtor de `\DateTime` teve para ler o argumento usando o método `getLastErrors`:

```
var_dump($data->getLastErrors());
```

Resultado:

```
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(1) {
    [18]=>
    string(27) "The parsed date was invalid"
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tive esse mesmo problema e usei uma solução bem simples pra verificar.

Quando o `DateTime` é criado com essa data nula, o método `format` retorna `-1` para o ano. Caso retorne algum valor acima de 0, significa que a data é válida.

```
if((int)$date->format('y') > 0) {
 // válida!
} else {
 // inválida!
}
```

Comment: Achei um jeito nativo para validar a data, veja a resposta que postei.